How to make a sheets calendar task repeat until its due date
Right now I'm working on a calendar system in sheets for my work team that syncs up to our tasklist. So far it's going well, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to list a task each day until its due date.
Currently I utilise a helper column and a countif to grab all the tasks on the day they were posted, but I can't seem to figure out how I'd make the tasks repeat after their assigned date until their due date.
Task list page
Calendar

If would be helpful to have the formulas you are currently using. It would also be useful to see the column/row IDs in your screencaps so we know which one is which.

My bad, I wanted to upload a project file but stackexchange doesn't seem to provide file hosting in that way. This is a link the xlsx in my drive, please let me know if it's accessible

It's better to include sample data as a markdown table and formulas as text. Otherwise your question becomes useless in the future when the link to the file goes dead. (also some people are not allowed to download files from unknown sources)


You may try:
=ifna(filter(if(data!$F:$F=B11,"!DUE! ",)&data!$H:$H&" | "&data!$G:$G,map(data!$E:$E,data!$F:$F,lambda(Σ,Λ,isbetween(B11,Σ,Λ)))))



Would you be able to explain how this formula works to achieve my goal? Also is the greek alphabet a personal preference or is it preferred for uses such as this

1, Its a simple filter function which checks if the given date(say July 15) is in between the given start and end dates. 2, you can use any other name_identifier of your choice. look into lambda()
